# Customizing change Text and Background Color of row Item programmatically in Android

Tags: android, listview

I have already fill adapter into `Listview` and it works fine.

My problem is how to change Text and Background color in specific row Item (using TextView) when selected.

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            int visiblePosition = listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View view = (View)listView1.getChildAt(position);
.....
    });
```

But it doesn't work as well.

By the way, please show me how to prevent loading data when scrolling in Listview (using custom adapter) or how to fill adapter into all row when first run.

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't work because the children of a listview are being re-used each time you scroll.

you should either update the data and call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) , or update the data and use something like:

```
int visiblePosition = mListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View view = mListView.getChildAt(position - visiblePosition);
if(view!=null)
  {
  // update the view to have a different background and other stuff...
  }
```

notes about the second way:

- on some adapterViews the second way might not work as expected.
- i'm not sure what will happen when changing the size of the view .